# MySQL optimization hint for DNF

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

In MYSQL, some code from a Wordpress plugin that I don't want to change too much is running the following query:

```
SELECT * WHERE cond1 AND (field1 = val1 OR field2 = val2)
```

However, it runs very slowly despite that there are indexes on val1 and val2. (the slow query log confirms that it scans all rows.) Can I hint MYSQL that it should always expand the formula to the following equivalent but faster form?

```
SELECT * WHERE cond1 AND (field1 = val1)
UNION
SELECT * WHERE cond1 AND (field2 = val2)
```

This would reduce the number of rows scanned dramatically, so it would yield vastly superior performance. I also wonder the same about

```
SELECT * WHERE cond1 AND (field1 in (val1, val2))
```

Thanks!

**Edit**: some info about the table and the query explanation are here at http://pastebin.com/Qd1ZaVKD but it seems inconsistent. If I run the query from myphpadmin sometimes a slow query log entry is generated and sometimes not, even if it continues to be generated when other users are causing such a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It first depends on `cond1`, and then on the cardinality of `field1` and `field2` under that condition:

1. If `cond1` involves direct comparisons of columns with constant values (i.e. an index can help to resolve it), then a composite index with `field1` and/or `field2` may help (see below).

   If `cond1` involves manipulations on columns—e.g. applying a function or other operations, such as `my_int + 5 = 3` or `DATE(my_timestamp) > NOW()`—then an index cannot help; however, note that both of those examples can be rewritten to be index-friendly:

   - `my_int = 3 - 5`, which is obviously equivalent to `my_int = -2`; and
   - `my_timestamp >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.
2. It's only ever worth creating indexes that have relatively high cardinality (i.e. can quickly distinguish between many records), otherwise using it will be little better than a full table scan whilst slowing down table write operations and consuming additional storage and memory space.  Consider not only the cardinality of `cond1`, `field1` and `field2`, but also that of `cond1` together with each of the fields.

   Assuming that they all have high cardinality, your best bet would be to achieve an [`index_merge` (union access)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-union) with two composite indexes on each of `(cond1, field1)` and `(cond1, field2)`.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. I don't even see why it should work, since the composite index would still need to be searched repeatedly to catch all of the rows with field2 = val2. Moreover, adding both the composite indexes (field1, field2) and (field2, field1) together does not even stop the problem, I have checked this with an experiment.

Comment: Done, at http://pastebin.com/Qd1ZaVKD but (see statement above) it doesn't stay consistent...?

Comment: @daveagp: Oh, my bad - I misread your question.  In this case, I don't see any usable index defined: as indeed the output of `EXPLAIN` shows with `Type: ALL` and `key: NULL` (i.e. a full table scan).  With this query, your best bet would be to achieve an [`index_merge` (union access)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-union) with indexes on `(scope, role_type, group_id)` and `(scope, role_type, user_id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! (Yeah cond1 is not a row but instead a boolean condition). This has definitely worked! I'm going to pass along your suggestion to the plugin developer.